# Deploying MicroStack, I get the error "Timed out while waiting for application 'microk8s' to be ready"

Tags: juju, openstack, microk8s

I'm trying to install [MicroStack](https://microstack.run/docs/multi-node), but it's stuck on the microk8s deployment, dropping out by the following error:

`$ sunbeam cluster bootstrap --role control --role compute --role storage`

```
Management networks shared by hosts (CIDRs, separated by comma) (172.16.1.0/24): 
MetalLB address allocation range (supports multiple ranges, comma separated) (172.16.1.201-172.16.1.220): 
⠏ Deploying MicroK8S ... Timed out while waiting for application 'microk8s' to be ready

Error: Timed out while waiting for application 'microk8s' to be ready
```

Running `sunbeam` with the *-v* switch:

```
           DEBUG    Running command /snap/openstack/324/bin/terraform apply -auto-approve -no-color                                                    terraform.py:199
⠹ Deploying MicroK8S ... [21:10:45] DEBUG    Command finished. stdout=data.juju_model.controller: Reading...                                                                    terraform.py:208
                    data.juju_model.controller: Read complete after 0s [id=055c3c7f-2b1e-45d1-8ff0-bffb975c6683]                                                       
                    juju_application.microk8s: Refreshing state... [id=controller:microk8s]                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                       
                    No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                       
                    Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration                                                                         
                    and found no differences, so no changes are needed.                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                       
                    Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.                                                                                        
                    , stderr=                                                                                                                                          
⠏ Deploying MicroK8S ...            DEBUG    Application 'microk8s' is in status: 'maintenance'                                                                                      juju.py:509
⠏ Deploying MicroK8S ... [21:13:45] WARNING  Timed out while waiting for application 'microk8s' to be ready                                                                      microk8s.py:180
           DEBUG    Finished running step 'Deploy MicroK8S'. Result: ResultType.FAILED                                                                    common.py:260
Error: Timed out while waiting for application 'microk8s' to be ready
```